# Method to simulate multitouch (n > 2) on ios?

Tags: ios-simulator, multi-touch

Is there a method to add a third (or more) touch location on the iOS simulator?

Holding down the **Option** key will give you a second touch point... but I haven't figured out how to enable more and would like to.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This app & framework, iSimulator, seem to be good ways of doing this, if you're still looking for this to be answered.

> iSimulate is an application/library pair designed to solve the issue
>   of not being able to use multi-touch and the accelerometer in the
>   iPhone Simulator. Now, with iSimulate on your iPhone or iPod Touch, it
>   wirelessly sends multi-touch events, the accelerometer and compass
>   events, and the GPS location to the iPhone Simulator.

http://www.vimov.com/isimulate/features/

Saw it mentioned here:
http://iosdevelopertips.com/tools/isimulate-testing-multi-touch-events-accelerometer-movements-using-xcode-simulator.html